# jQuery or vanilla JS - return r, g & b values for background color of element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure why this one is haunting me. I have a grid of event cards. Each card has a button with the same background color. How do I return the rbg value of that button class, in this example`event-button`?

```
<div class="event-grid">
  <div class="event-card">
    <button class="event-button">Buy Tickets</button> // return r, g & b values for bg color
  </div>
  <div class="event-card">
    <button class="event-button">Buy Tickets</button> 
  </div>
  <div class="event-card">
    <button class="event-button">Buy Tickets</button> 
  </div>
  <div class="event-card">
    <button class="event-button">Buy Tickets</button> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what are you trying to get? The `rgb` values of the background color of class of the button that was clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the `r`, `g`, `b` and `a` value of the css class definition, you can use `getComputedStyle` [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Please find the working fiddle.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button.event-button').forEach((button) => {
  button.onclick = function(e) {
    const styles = window.getComputedStyle(e.target);
    const background = styles.getPropertyValue("background-color");
    const [red, green, blue, alpha] = background.replace(/^(rgb|rgba)\(/,'').replace(/\)$/,'').replace(/\s/g,'').split(',');
    console.log(red, green, blue);
  }
});
```

```css
.event-button {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="event-grid">
  <div class="event-card">
    <button class="event-button">Buy Tickets</button> // return r, g & b values for bg color
  </div>
  <div class="event-card">
    <button class="event-button">Buy Tickets</button>
  </div>
  <div class="event-card">
    <button class="event-button">Buy Tickets</button>
  </div>
  <div class="event-card">
    <button class="event-button">Buy Tickets</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir. You are awesome.